# How to set timeout in socket programming? Close a port to let the program execute the next step

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am now using C language for socket programming.I want to simulate the implementation of FTP protocol.I have two ports, one for authentication and the other for receiving data.When one port is verified successfully, the other port will be opened for data transmission with the client. When the data transmission port does not receive data for more than 30s, it will be closed. How to close another port when the data is not accepted for more than 30s, and the program executes the next step

Answer (score 4):

You can either:

- use `select()` or `(e)poll()` to wait with a timeout for data to arrive before then `recv()`'ing the data.
- use `setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO)` to set a timeout for a blocking `recv()`